# mercurial equivalent to `git remotes -v`

Tags: mercurial, equivalent, git-remote

I want to see a list of stored remote locations (as in url's) from which I can pull from.

With git, I can do `git remote -v`

Is there an equivalent with mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hg paths
```

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#paths

(seriously, there is nothing to add more)

Comment: I thought there'd be something. I found you can also look at the `[paths]` section in `.hg/hgrc`.

Comment: @drevicko: in git you could also look at `.git/config` :-)